# OnMouseDown in prefab not working with some scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, scene, onmousedown, prefab

I have prefab enemyRangeAttack and then I add this code for enemy (child of enemyRangeAttack)

```
public class Selectable : MonoBehaviour{

[HideInInspector] public GameObject Player;
public float range = 10f;

private void Awake()
{
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
}


private void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.LogWarning("Mouse down "+ gameObject);

    float dist = Vector3.Distance(Player.transform.position, transform.position);

    if (dist < range)
    {
        Selected();
    }

}

public void Selected()
{
   GameObject newSelection = ObjectPooler.instance.SpawnFromPool(
            "Mark",
            transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.transform.position,
            Quaternion.identity
        );
    newSelection.transform.SetParent(transform);
}
}
```

Game object enemyRangeAttack have circle collider2d and trigger is on and Game object enemy have too

And I have 3 scene, method OnMouseDown() not working for all my scene. How can I fix this

Comment: **Pro tip:** `[HideInInspector] public GameObject Player` if you turn that into a _property_ it is _automatically hidden from the Unity inspector._ :)

Comment: [MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) only works on the [Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html) class, which doesn't include any 2d colliders.

Comment: @MickyD it is not master. I find GameObject on Awake and Update function. I thing it has same effective

Comment: @Voidsay Yes, I have Collider class. What I say is: It work but only on 1 scene, 2 scene other is not. I use prefap so it must be same. Right?

Comment: @NgDat you've mentioned in your description that you are using a `circle collider2d`, which is derived from `Collider2D` and **not** `Collider`. It is confusing to me that it even works in one scene.

Comment: @Voidsay I'm new with Unity and trying create 2D game. So, It is confusing to me too. Too strange

Comment: @NgDat I have to apologize. Looks like I've been telling you lies. Just tried it and it works with 2d colliders also.
Regarding your actual issue, make sure that there are no colliders blocking the one with the script and that you haven't put it on a layer that ignores raycasts.

Comment: I added Raycast2D to Update. Luckily it works 2 out of 3 scenes. Now, I use 2 way to check :v and it work all 3 scene. It's complicated